Algorithm to find what percentage of all k sized subgraphs include a vertex for all vertex
I am trying to analyse connected, undirected graphs to find which vertices are most critical. The way I am doing this is by finding how often a vertex shows up amongst all the connected subgraphs with k nodes.
As an example, given the input [{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 3}, {2, 4}, {4, 5}], we have n = 5 total nodes. If we look at all the k = 3 subgraphs: {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 4}, {2, 3, 4}, {2, 4, 5}, we should get {1: 0.5, 2: 1.0, 3: 0.5, 4: 0.75, 5: 0.25}.
Ideally, I would like to do this for a n = 50 graph for subgraphs of size k = 20, and each vertex will have a maximum of 4 edges associated (think square lattice with some vertices missing).
I should be able to generate all subgraphs using this paper, but I think there should be a smarter and more efficient way of doing this: https://consystlab.unl.edu/Documents/StudentReports/TR-UNL-CSE-2013-0005.pdf
My previous attempt was to generate all combinations of k - 1 edges and seeing if I get k unique vertices, then updating the counters for each vertex, and finally dividing by the total number of trees.
I know I can approximate this by randomly getting the edge combinations, but itertools.combinations returns an iterable, and shuffling it takes too much space. I did start with Python, but I am not sure if C++ would be much better without a significant change in the algorithm.
In conclusion, I would prefer either a smarter algorithm, or someway to get random sampling that I can run for t time or i iterations.
Edit:
An alternate approach could be someway to count all the possible k sized trees that include a given vertex, possibly via breadth first search, and run this in parallel for all n vertices. Is there an efficient way of doing this? I am willing to give up finding out the exact percentage, and just getting the total numbers, if this is the case.

"I should be able to generate all subgraphs using this paper, but I think there should be a smarter and more efficient way of doing this". What about you start with that? There seems to be quite a lot of effort that was spent working on this problem. If that doesn't work for you, you can look into developing you own algo and publish a paper. I'm not sure SO is the place where you will find 'smarter' than published algos. Try some more specific graph analytics forums maybe.

@MrE Thanks for the comment! It's just that my question does not necessarily need all the subgraphs listed, so hopefully it should be possible to optimise for that. I have added some other thoughts in the edit.

if you only need the subgraphs with a specificvertex, it seems like you could just break off/skip the loops in the algo in the paper when the vertex is not present. but eventually don't you want to do this for every vertex? in which case getting all subgraphs once, and then looping and filtering per vertex for each vertex computation might work well.

I think https://cs.stackexchange.com/ is better place for such type of question
